# Using a monadic boolean value in a guard? (PatternGuard)

Tags: haskell, monads

I just found out about the [PatternGuards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard) language extension, which seems really nice.

I'm in a situation where I want to pattern match a value out, apply a monadic boolean function on that value, and only do something if the result is `False`. Otherwise I want to execute a default action (that might not be as simple as listed below).

This can be achieved by using an `if` after doing the pattern matching, but I would rather not duplicate the code for the default action, or move that out in a separate function (ie. keep the fall through behaviour of guards)

Is there a way to do this *without* the `if`?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, PatternGuards #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State

newtype MyM a = MyM (StateT Int (Either String) a)
                deriving ( MonadState Int
                         , Monad, Applicative, Functor
                         )

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

foo :: Int -> MyM Bool
foo = undefined

bar :: Either a Int -> MyM Int
bar (Right n)
  | ok <- foo n, ok == False = return 42
bar _ = return 0
```

The above code gives the error message

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘MyM Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘False’
In the expression: ok == False
```

Comment: Have you considered using `where` and `if`?

Comment: Despite the similarity in syntax, pattern guards simply aren't monadic, and I don't know any way to get pattern fall-through to continue after a monadic action. I can think of workarounds using `mplus` and monad transformers, but they're going to be *more* complicated than just biting the bullet and separating out the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible, and for good reasons. Let's say that `foo` modifies the state, but the condition in the guard doesn't match. How would you deal with this state modification? Patterns are separate from the values, so matching a pattern can't result in altering results.
You really need to have the call to `foo` in the RHS that decides what to do with its output.

In some cases, where the monad is a data type you can match on, you can do things like

```
foo :: Int -> Maybe Bool
...

bar :: Either a Int -> MyM Int
bar (Right n)
  | Just False <- foo n = ...
```

but only because you can match directly on the value of the monad.

Also in some cases extensions [lambda-case and multi-way if-expressions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#lambda-case) can make your life somewhat easier.